# Determine if ActiveRecord Object is New

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How can I check if an `ActiveRecord` object is new or is already persisted?

Answer (score 416, accepted):

An ActiveRecord object lifecycle:

1.**new record**

```
item = Item.new
item.new_record? #=> true
```

2.**persisted**

```
item.save
item.persisted? #=> true
```

3.**changed**

```
item.name = "other"
item.changed? #=> true
```

4.**destroyed**

```
item.destroy
item.destroyed? #=> true
```

Comment: I'd like to add `item.previously_new_record?` and `item.previously_persisted?` to the list

Answer (score 317):

[`#new_record?`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/new_record%3F) does just that:

```
object.new_record?
```