# Check to see if record is newly created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I can't figure out how to check to see if a record is newly saved. right now I am using

```
 If @item.save
      @a = Item.where(“restaurant_id = ?”, params[:item][:user_id]).where(“created_at < ?”, 2.minutes.ago)
```

The query is working fine but I'm wondering if there is a better way to check to see if the record was just created. I was looking into ActiveModel::Dirty but once the record is saved, :created_at_changed? will return false.

Comment: check out this question + answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842920/determine-if-activerecord-object-is-new-or-created

Comment: Or even http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842920/determine-if-activerecord-object-is-new-or-created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think rails provide any method to check this. You can implement your own using ActiveRecord.

```
def recently_created?
  Item.where("restaurant_id = ? AND created_at < ?", params[:items][:user_id], 2.minutes.ago)
end
```

If you want it for all the ActiveRecord models, add it to the ActiveRecord::Base class.

Answer (score 17):

For the record, Rails 4 and 5 now both have functionality for this.

In Rails 4, you can do:

```
@item.previous_changes.key?('id')
```

And in Rails 5:

```
@item.id_previously_changed?
```

[NOTE: This assumes you never manually update the IDs of your records. If you are, you'll need something more like the following:]

```
@item.previous_changes.key?('id') && @item.previous_changes['id'][0].nil?
```

Answer (score 5):

Since Rails 6.1 you can use:

```rb
@item.previously_new_record?
```