# Rails count vs. size model records when creating new record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a shopping cart in my Rails app. I am trying to display the number of items that are currently in the user's cart and update it asynchronously as the user adds items. I am displaying (and updating) this counter in the same controller action where you can create new cart items. The behavior is like this:

**In the View**

```
<%= link_to "#{current_user.cart_items.size} Items in Cart", cart_items_path, class: "btn btn-default" %>
```

**In the Controller**

```
def index
  @cart_item = current_user.cart_item.new # instantiate a new cart_item to be used in a form to create a new cart_item in this index action
end
```

So every time the View is loaded the `current_user.cart_items.size` count is one too many since the Action is instantiating a new cart_item.

I tried it out in the console to verify:

```
2.2.1 :022 > current_user.cart_items.size
 => 2 
2.2.1 :023 > current_user.cart_items.new
 => #<CartItem id: nil, user_id: 1, product_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
2.2.1 :024 > current_user.cart_items.size
 => 3
```

Is there any way to **not** count an object that is only instantiated an not yet saved?

**Note:** I tried this with `build` too in place of `new` and it had the same result.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine if ActiveRecord Object is New Or Created](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842920/determine-if-activerecord-object-is-new-or-created)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `count` method instead of use `size`.
For explanation, you need to know how `size` performs :

- If a collection is loaded, the method will count elements in collection ( as an array )
- If there is no loaded collection, the method perform a query.

In your situation, you want to perform a query as `count` method do :

`current_user.cart_items.count`

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [`new_record?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-new_record-3F):

> Returns true if this object hasn't been saved yet – that is, a record
>   for the object doesn't exist in the database yet; otherwise, returns
>   false.

so in your case you'd have something like this:

```ruby
@cart_item = current_user.cart_item.new
@cart_items.new_record? # false
```