# Ordering of callbacks in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am facing some issue with ordering callbacks in ActiveRecord. According to Rails [guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#available-callbacks), when creating an object the order of callbacks is as follows:

- before_validation
- after_validation
- before_save
- around_save
- before_create
- around_create
- after_create
- after_save
- after_commit/after_rollback

I have two callbacks in my model. One for after_save (to be run on create and update) and second for after_create. On create I want the after_create callback to be run only after after_save callback. How to get this done in ActiveRecord? Thanks.

Comment: Well, you can't reorder callbacks. So either put your logic into `after_save` (or later) or drop using callbacks altogether. In favor of, for example, some kind of Builder pattern.

Comment: I  do not see any purpose to do so as change of order of call due to `rails-3` to `rails-5` application upgrade. So changes as suggested by @SergioTulentsev are valid and preferable.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev How can I add `after_create` logic into `after_save`? `after_save`  will be run on updates also.

Comment: @BKS: off the top of my head, you can set a flag in `before_create`. Something like `self.record_was_just_created = true`. Then check this flag in `after_save`. If flag is true, run the create-specific parts. Me, I would extract this into separate builder/updated objects. Should make the build procedure obvious. And avoidable, when needed.

Comment: @BKS you can check whether record is new or not with `new_record?` . so in after_save call back check `self.new_record?`

Comment: @Vishal: `self.new_record?` still returns true in an `after_save`? I would think no, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Event i am also not sure about that. BKS has to check for it

Comment: @BKS you can use active model dirty here . use  `created_at_changed?` or `id_changed?`

Comment: Could you post additional info on what you are trying to solve? There is pretty sure a solution for it without messing with the integrated callbacks from rails and still be able to achieve  what you trying to do. after_create exists only once, after_save all the time. Therefore using after_save makes sense. Again, if you can, provide more code or infos and i'm sure theres a solution! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Do not change the behavior of the rails `call_backs` - *even if you knew how to, it makes it harder to work on the application later* - change where you place the code.

You are getting too hung up on the names of the `call_backs`.  When they run is more important.

Here is what we know about your design without making the assumptions about which are the best ways of achieving it ...

- You have a method that runs after a new record is created
- You have a method that runs after a old record is updated

Here is where you seem to change your design decisions in order to make programming easier - but in doing so are breaking best practices ...

- For some reason you believe the method for updating should run every time (`after_save`) instead of `after_update`)
- For some reason you believe the creation method should run after the method for updating (which is an unhealthy chaining of code)

Technically, the parts needed for both creating and updating should be divided out into a third method and called by both `after_create` & `after_update` so your code documents itself and is easier to understand.

All of this is relatively important - as most experienced programmers stress you should only utilize `call_backs` when no other way is reasonable - due to the how hard they are to conceptualization in trouble shooting obscure problems.

---

**Solution 1 - The Rails Way**

`after_save` should be used only for code that needs to run for both updates AND creations.  Any code that needs to run for one or the other should be broken up in smaller methods & then called as needed by `after_update` & `after_create` to keep it DRY.

**Solution 2 & 3 Refactoring old code without changing design**

1. Setup a working test to ensure your code fails and succeeds where you expect
2. `after_save` has to run - so we know it has to be there.  We wrap it in a method called '**update_method_code**' to encapsulate it.
3. Move the method definition for '**update_method_code**' somewhere in model or service object.
4. Leave the method call for '**update_method_code**' in the `after_save`.

*Since we didn't technically change anything the tests should be green.*

5. You code previously in `after_create` - wrap this in a method called '**new_object_code**' so it's encapsulated.
6. Move the method definition for '**new_object_code**' somewhere in model or service object.

This is where you have a few choices ...

- You can have '**update_method_code**' test using one of the four
  [activerecord lifecycle checks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18729841/4289112) to test call the method
  'new_object_code'.  This isn't good as it creates visibility issues
  and means if one fails the rest fails.  In a very heavy-handed way it
  ensures your condition of 'new_object_code' only runs after
  '**update_method_code**'
- You use the already built Rails methods. `after_save :update_method_code on: :create` to trigger the '**update_method_code**'.  See example here [Rails Guide for transactions](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#transaction-callbacks).  Keep in mind here, this might run even if your other `after_save` call does not ... so once again, this method is less sound than simply following the Rails Way & using `after_update` / `after_create`.

---

Good luck with your project!